PostGIS function that can extract duplicate lines

The line objects (two objects) in that part are duplicated. Is there a 'PostGIS function' that can extract that part?
I am inquiring because the results cannot be extracted using the st_overlap or st_intersects functions.
Is a postgis function that can extract duplicate objects?

It depends on whether they're really the same or just look the same. ST_Equals() checks that, ignoring the coordinate order (in case one line goes from A to B and the other is the same but goes from B to A). = and ST_OrderingEquals() preserve the coordinate order, so for the two lines to be equal they must start and end the same, in the same direction/order. If you check their ST_AsText(), do they report the same definitions? Are they the same if you zoom all the way in?

If you check ST_AsText(), the same coordinate values ​​are extracted.
By using the two functions you provided, duplicate values ​​can be easily extracted.
thank you
